# Django download file using CBV

Tags: django

How to use Class Based Views eg. TemplateView to display Django template with download links? Clicking the link should start downloading selected file. I already know how to do it with Function Based Views.

Also - is it good idea to put filename slug as URL parameter (filename) for GET requests or should I use different method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally what you're looking to do is send a request to the CBV and respond with a Response that contains your CSV.

I'm going to assume that you want to use the same CBV that you're using for e.g. your `TemplateView` already. For this I would setup a `def post(self, request)` method on the CBV for handling your specific request, something like:

```
class MyTemplateView(TemplateView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request_type = request.POST.get("type", [])
        
        # Check whether the request type indicates we should generate
        # a CSV
        if "generate_csv" in request_type:
            return self.generate_csv()

        return super(MyTemplateView, self).post(*args, **kwarfs)

    def generate_csv(self):
        response = HttpResponse(content_type="text/csv")
        response[
            "Content-Disposition"
        ] = 'attachment; filename="name_of_csv_download_{}.csv"'.format(
            time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        )

        writer = csv.writer(response)
        writer.writerow(
            [
                "Heading 1",
                "Heading 2",
                "Heading 3",
                etc
            ]
        )

        data = ...get data you want to write to csv...

        for row in data:
            writer.writerow(
                [
                    row.id,
                    row.property1,
                    row.property2,
                    etc
                ]
            )

        return response
```

So they key here is in setting the correct `content_type` on the response, along with the `Content-Disposition` header. In essence, it's no different to how we do things with function based views, [as detailed here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/outputting-csv/), and you could apply the exact same logic to your `def get(self, request)` using query parameters rather than post parameters to achieve the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

It's not such a bad creating slug with the file name as soon as you comply with your business logic and security related issue